# display events only one any symbol instead of names in FullCalendar v1.5.3

Tags: fullcalendar

In FullCalendar v1.5.3 events displaying names in date, for expample if there are 5 events in one date they all 5 event's name is displaying. I want that only show one any symbol (*) instead of names, when i clicked it should display events belong to this date! How can I set displaying?

Answer (score 0):

use className in array in json file.